# Method not being called when view loads

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a normal view controller with xib, m, and h file. I want when the view loads for it to automatically call a method. In my current M file I have the code call another view, this is just so I can see if the checkIfLogged method is working. When the app loads it doesn't call the other view it stays in its own view. How can I get the checkIfLogged method called when the viewloads? Actually I would prefer the method to be called before the view is even loaded if that is possible.

Here is my M file.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "LoginView.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    [self checkIfLogged];
}

- (void) checkIfLogged
{
    LoginView *loginView = [[LoginView alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil];
    [loginView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet]; //you can change the way it is presented
    [loginView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical]; //you can change the animation
    [self presentViewController:loginView animated:YES completion:nil]; //show the modal view


}//end checkIfLogged

@end
```

Here is my H file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

-(IBAction)checkIfLogged;

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

First, call `[super viewDidLoad];` as the first line in your `viewDidLoad` implementation.

Second, you shouldn't attempt to present a view controller from `viewDidLoad`. Your UIViewController's view is not part of the view hierarchy at this point. Present the view controller from `viewDidAppear:` instead.